# ExactTarget AMPScript Date Function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date

I would like to use AMPScript to automate a date range, e.g.:

Prices effective: Tuesday, June 3 through Monday, June 9, 2014 unless otherwise noted.

I have:

Prices effective: `%%xtdayofweek%%`, `%%xtmonth%%` `%%xtday%%` through `%%=Format(DateAdd(Now(), "6","D"), "MM/dd/yyyy")=%%` unless otherwise noted.

But `%%=Format(DateAdd(Now(), "6","D"), "MM/dd/yyyy")=%%` returns:
`06/09/2014`

How do I parse/convert/format/concat it into "Monday, June 9, 2014"?

Answer (score 2):

While `FormatDate()` can be limiting I commonly will return a full date as a variable and then use format for displaying the data. so first I grab the date `@TheDateVar` then `FormatDate(V1,S1,S2,S3)` which allows better but not unlimited flexibility for presentation.

Then `SET @DateFormatted = FormatDate(@TheDateVar,"DDD, MMM DD, YYYY",S2,S3)`

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Format (then scroll a couple items down)

Answer (score 1):

FormatDate supports all C# date formatting strings.

So, you will need to replace "MM/dd/yyyy" with "D", which is the C# symbol for the "long date"

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  for the list of these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above provided by Timothy will produce a time stamp.

```
%%=FORMAT(DateAdd(Now(), "X","D"), "MMMM dd, yyyy")=%%
```

With X being how many days from now you want.